# Error: Connection activation failed: Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable

Tags: centos, networking

I have a CentOS server that is currently using `eth1` network interface. I am trying to change it to `eth0` and have configured it but when I try `ifup eth0` I get this error message:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable
```

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` are as follows:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=6519f5da-294a-45e3-b9dc-b8aa12c5fda3
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
HWADDR=00:19:99:D5:56:95
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
LAST_CONNECT=1509619482
```

Please can someone help in getting `eth0` up?

Answer (score 1):

system-config-network

select the eth0 device and hit the Edit button
and uncheck the "Controlled by network manager" check box and check the box for Activating the port when the computer starts up. Save and quit in there.

Now run system-config-services and stop/disable NetworkManager and start/enabled network service.

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

If you run `ifconfig -a` or `ip link show` as root, does the eth0 interface appear in the output? Does it have the MAC address that ís specified in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file on the `HWADDR=` line?

If it is not there at all, then the driver for the NIC has probably not been loaded yet, or has a problem that prevents it from loading.
If it has an unexpected name, you may have a problem with NIC naming.

If the NIC is there with the expected name, but refuses to activate, it might be a firmware loading problem: some NICs require firmware to work, and if the necessary firmware file is not available, the driver cannot activate the NIC. If this is the problem, then the `dmesg | less` listing will usually contain one or more messages indicating that the system cannot load a specific firmware file. Once you know the name of the firmware file, you can search for it. Make sure the `linux-firmware-<YYYYMMDD>-<version number>` RPM package is installed: it includes a large collection of firmware files for various hardware.

Comment: In my case there is a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto-eth0` but `ifconfig` gives name of device as `eth0`. Is it a signal of problem with NIC driver?

Comment: @LRDPRDX If the contents of the `ifcfg-Auto-eth0` file still say `DEVICE=eth0`, then it's probably just a quirk of the network configuration tools you're using. If it says `DEVICE=Auto-eth0` instead, then it might be a timing issue between udev renaming the interface and the configuration tool starting to write the initial configuration for the device before udev was finished with it. In other words, the creators of the distribution may have made some kind of mistake when integrating the various system components together. Unlikely to be a driver problem, unless its HW detection is very slow.

Comment: Ok, I am still confused. I tried many centos versions and it was always a problem with network connection. Eventilually, i have installed SL 7, tried every possible solutions i've found. Still no network. Then I powered off computer and unplugged cabel for a minute and powered on back. And connection appeared.

Comment: @LRDPRDX please ask your own question instead of piggy-backing onto someone else's question. But sounds like it might be a hardware incompatibility between the NIC and whatever is at the other end of the network cable. Knowing the exact models of the NIC and the switch (or whatever) would be important here.